# add a new column in the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

If I want to add a new column to the data frame, which is the divisor of the first two columns, is this the right way to do it?

```
Newcolumn <- sum(Data$column1)/sum(Data$column2)
NewcolumnCol<- data.frame(Newcolumn,col.names=Newcolumn) 
allData <- merge(Newcolumn, Data)
```

Comment: You can just do `Data <- transform(Data, NewColumn = sum(column1)/sum(column2))` or `Data$NewColumn <- with(Data, sum(column1)/sum(column2))`

Comment: what's the difference between using merge and transform?

Comment: Or `Data <- within(Data, { NewColumn = sum(column1)/sum(column2) })`. Having said that, I find it unsatisfying to add a scalar to every row.

Comment: `merge` you are doing more work i.e while the `transform` is more direct

Comment: `transform` modifies columns, while `merge` matches the rows from one frame with rows from another based on one or more common columns; `merge` can end up with many more rows than either frame had in the first place. It is not the right tool here. You can think of `merge` as performing a lookup of sorts; imagine merging `data.frame(zipcode=1:3,state=c('a','b','c'))` with a long long frame of `data.frame(zipcode=c(1,1,2,2,1,3,1,...),fname=c(...),lname=c(...))` in order to match the `state` with each of the rows in the second frame.

Comment: I guess transform is much easier to use hhhh Thank you !!!

Comment: It's a different tool, that's all. `merge` (and the tidy variants `*_join` and the `data.table` methods) all do great things ... when it is the appropriate thing to do. Yes, I think the concept of `transform` is perhaps learned sooner in the data-science-y learning path, but I suggest that merging/joining tables is (to me) one of the logical next-steps.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `transform` instead of `merge`ing to directly create the column and update the 'Data'

```
Data <- transform(Data, NewColumn = sum(column1)/sum(column2))
```

Or simply create the new column by assignment

```
Data$NewColumn <- with(Data, sum(column1)/sum(column2))
```

The division of `sum` of two columns returns a single  and that gets recycled to the number of rows of the dataset with the assignment.

`merge` is mostly done when we have two datasets with one or more columns to match while doing the assignment.  Here, it is not the case